# Merge lists of dictionaries based on matching values in one key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
dicte = [{'value':3, 'content':'some_string'}, {'value':4, 'content':'some_string1'}, {'value':4, 'content':'some_string2'}, {'value':4, 'content':'some_string3'}, {'value':4, 'content':'some_string4'}, {'value':5, 'content':'some_string5'}]
```

I want to be able to do an operation on that dictionary so that all the `content` that got the same values regarding the key `"value"` are regrouped and generate another dictionary based on that

The result here should be

```
new_dicte = [{'value':3, 'content':['some_string']}, {'value':4, 'content':['some_string1', 'some_string2', 'some_string3', 'some_string4']}, {'value':5, 'content':['some_string5']}]
```

What is the best pythonic way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `dict.setdefault` method to collect `value`-`content` pairs and unpacking later:

```
out = {}
for d in dicte:
    out.setdefault(d['value'],[]).append(d['content'])
new_dicte = list(map(lambda x: dict(zip(('value','content'), x)), out.items()))
```

Here's another method that doesn't use an intermediate dictionary:

```
out = {}
for d in dicte:
    if d['value'] not in out:
        out[d['value']] = {'value':d['value'], 'content':[d['content']]}
    else:
        out[d['value']]['content'].append(d['content'])
new_dicte = list(out.values())
```

Output:

```
[{'value': 3, 'content': ['some_string']},
 {'value': 4,
  'content': ['some_string1', 'some_string2', 'some_string3', 'some_string4']},
 {'value': 5, 'content': ['some_string5']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

"Pythonic" is debatable, but you could build an intermediate dict to group by value:

```
grouped_by_value = {}

for item in dicte:
    if item["value"] not in grouped_by_value:
        grouped_by_value[item["value"]] = []

    grouped_by_value[item["value"]].append(item["content"])

new_dicte = [{"value": key, "content": val} for key, val in grouped_by_value.items()]
```

The order of the elements in the `new_dicte` **list** will be the order that the values are encountered in the `dicte` **list**, assuming you are using a Python version where dicts are sorted by insertion order.

If you want to guarantee a specific ordering for `new_dicte`, you can sort the items of the `grouped_by_value.items()`, for example, by increasing "value" key.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Pythonic** is **debatable** but I would personally go with something like this,

```py
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

resp = defaultdict(list)

for key,group in itertools.groupby(d, key=lambda x: x["value"]):
    for thing in group:
        resp[key].append(thing.get("content"))

print(resp)
```

Output (can be adjusted to the way we want...)

```
{3: ['some_string'],
 4: ['some_string1', 'some_string2', 'some_string3', 'some_string4'],
 5: ['some_string5']}
```